# Node is openning a new cmd tab

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: The tab that npm open]Always when I make a node command, for example npm, my node opens a new cmd tab and then execute the command, but it is difficulting my npm install actions, because when it have an error, it closes before I can read all of the error text, can someone help me?

Comment: Seems like software configuration issue.

Comment: What can I do about it?